# Could mosquitoes be attracted to the sound of their blood host?

Tags: insect, air, attraction

At long-range, female mosquitoes mostly rely on CO2 to find blood host by flying up-wind following the odor plume ([ref](https://doi.org/10.1017/S1742758400020816)). They are also known to have **excellent auditory organs** ([ref1](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspb.2000.1021), [ref2](https://doi.org/10.1242/jeb.243535)) involved in mating ([ref](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2421604)).

Could female mosquitoes **detect the sound of their host (call, etc) to locate them**, and then bypass their dependence to the wind direction to find the blood host?

Comment: Worth noting a similar question on the [biology stack](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/107271/5509).

Comment: well spotted! that's mine too :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although females of most species does not behaviourally respond to ecologically-relevant intensity levels of sounds, females of at least a few species are attracted to the playback of frog calls (they blood feed on frogs):

- *[Culex territans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culex_territans)* ([Bartlett-Healy et al., 2008](https://doi.org/10.1603/0013-8746(2008)101%5B95:PTAVIC%5D2.0.CO;2)),
- *[Uranotaenia lowii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranotaenia_lowii)* ([Borkent & Belton 2006](http://europepmc.org/abstract/AGR/IND44019390))

or to traps baited with pure-frequency sounds:

- *[Culex tritaeniorhynchus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culex_tritaeniorhynchus)* which blood-feeds on cattle, swine and human ([Ikeshoji, 1986](https://doi.org/10.7601/mez.37.153))
- *[Mansonia uniformis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mansonia_uniformis)* which blood-feeds on human and birds ([Ogawa, 1988](https://doi.org/10.1303/aez.23.265))